# Run python parallel processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have more than 20 independent scripts that I need to execute I don't know exactly how many processes I can execute in parallel as good practice:

```
import os
import glob
from multiprocessing import Pool

processos = (
    'p1.py',
    'p2.py',
    'p3.py',
    'p4.py',
    'p5.py',
    'p6.py',
    'p7.py',
    'p8.py',
    'p9.py',
    'p10.py',
    'p11.py',
    'p12.py',
    'p13.py',
    'p14.py',
    'p15.py',
    'p16.py',
    'p17.py',
    'p18.py',
    'p19.py',
    'p20.py',
    'p21.py',
    'p22.py',
    'p23.py',
    'p24.py'
)
def roda_processo(processo):                                                            
    os.system('python {}'.format(processo))


pool = Pool(processes=24)                                                        
pool.map(roda_processo, processos)
```

Would you like to know the most effective way to run these scripts.

Detail: These processes will run with schedules.

Comment: There is no "correct" answer here, it depends on the specifics of what you are doing and your system etc

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But if I have 25 processes run at once, can there be any problems? exemple: `pool = Pool(process=25)`

Comment: Yes there could be. Or there could not. Have you *encountered* any problems? Note, a typical computer handles very many processes

Comment: I no longer realized how much the processor demands the processors thought there might be.

Comment: Error: `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'run_process' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>`

Comment: If you're seeing that, you haven't defined a function named `run_process`.  The code you posted won't even get that far, so clearly you're running something differently than what you posted.

Comment: @AnonCoward Just translate to English, my code is in Portuguese, I edited now as it is here.

Comment: Your code works now.  Are you running it in a notebook or other interactive environment?  If so, don't do that, multiprocessing generally should only be run from a script file.

Comment: I am running on a notebook using the terminal:
`python scripts.py`, where scripts.py is this code I posted.
I how then test this code?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use shell?

`` seq 1 24 | xargs -L1 -I{} -P`nproc` python p{}.py ``

```
 -P maxprocs
         Parallel mode: run at most maxprocs invocations of utility at
         once.

 nproc
          print the number of processing units available
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel you can do:

```
parallel python ::: p*.py
```

It will spawn one process per CPU thread.

If your processes only use 30% CPU power (e.g. maybe it is waiting for the network the rest of the time) it makes sense to spawn 3 times as many:

```
parallel -j300% python ::: p*.py
```